# async/await in react with redux

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux

Hi guys I am quite new to programming and trying to understand one thing with redux and await/async functions. Basically I have this function:

```
 //nh functions
    const onSubmit = async data => {
        try{
            await dispatch(Login(data))
            if (auth.logged != false){
                addToast(content, { appearance: 'success', autoDismiss: true, })
                history.push('/')
            } else if (auth.logged == false){
                addToast(content2, { appearance: 'error', autoDismiss: true, })
            }
        }finally{
            console.log('Tada')
        }
    }
```

which should first authenticate an account and then push a notification. However, the await is not working at all, and it proceeds immediately to the if statement. Any tips?

Comment: `dispatch` is not asynchronous. The results of the action are, but that isn’t handled via async/await, rather by prop/state changes.

Comment: What is the behaviour of the onSubmit once the dispatch has finished? Other than redirecting, does it make any state changes to the component? Also how is auth.logged changed?

Answer (score 1):

Wht dave said is true. If you want to do something like that, you should dispatch your data and get the result in a props. Then you can use a `useEffect` to listen to this prop and do your things. Somethink like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Do your things after your dispatch here
}, [yourProp]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The "normal" pattern is to write asynchronous pseudo-actions: async function dispatching classical synchronous actions :

```
// reducer

// define 3 synchronous actions : loginActionBegin, loginActionSuccess,
// loginActionFailure which update your state at your convenience, for example setting a boolean flag to inform components that request is
// flying, or add user infos in store when loginActionSuccess is dispatched...

// async pseudo action
export const loginActionAsync = (loginInfos: any): any => {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch, getState: any): any => {
    dispatch(loginActionBegin());
    return loginService.login(loginInfos)
      .then(result: any): any => {
        // request succeeded, add toast, user feedback...
        dispatch(loginActionSuccess(result));
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        // request failed, add toast, user feedback...
        dispatch(loginActionFailure(error));
      });
  };
}
```

Then in a component:

```
// grab infos from store
const user = useSelector(state => state.user)

// on login form submit
dispatch(loginActionAsync({username:..., password:...}));
```

You will need async middleware to do so like https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

See :

- https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/redux-redux-thunk
- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `auth` is a prop that is mapped from the redux state to the component?

If so you could get around having to create an async functionality for the submit button and handling the redirect and/or state change when the component is updated with a new value from the store.

I would recommend this as you should rather be handling any error in the action itself, that way the component can be kept simple and mainly focuses on what to display.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (auth.logged != false){
      addToast(content, { appearance: 'success', autoDismiss: true, })
      history.push('/')
   } 
   else if (auth.logged == false){
      addToast(content2, { appearance: 'error', autoDismiss: true, })
   }
}, [auth.logged]);

const onSubmit = data => dispatch(Login(data))
```

Comment: this almost did it, except one detail. The onSubmit is called after the user presses the button "login". The idea was to dispatch and then according to the auth.logged to reply a toast. My problem was that it did not work with the asynchronous idea.